# Ms HelpViewer 2.2 for Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, frameworks, help-viewer

I'm using VS 2015 and why I can't see documentation for **ASP.Net core,  ASP.Net Core API Reference,  Nuget &  MVC**

in Ms Help Viewer 2.2 ? [This is My Last update Ms Help Viewer 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV3Uk.jpg)

Meanwhile, [VS 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/04/19/visual-studio-2017-offline-books-available-for-download/) is more complete.
Does Anyone has same issue ?

Rgds,

Comment: I guess they finally know everything should simply be online at http://learn.microsoft.com

Comment: Not everyone can access the online documentation.